# Setting time requirements in Solidity

Tags: solidity, timestamp, require, datetime

I want a function to only be able to be called after a certain specific period of time has passed from the contract's inception. Generally, I was using block.number for that. As in:

```
require(block.number >= 8000000);
```

However, if I want to use block.timestamp, could I do as below:

```
contract Time is owned {

    uint today;

    constructor() public {
       today = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Declare 'today', and then set a requirement:

```
require (block.timestamp >= today + 365 days);
```

Will that work in preventing that the function gets called before 365 days pass from the publishing of the contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're totally right! The way you do has no problem. You can make a test with small time like `require (block.timestamp >= today + 60 seconds);`

Comment: But be aware that the time should not be too small in practice. Miners can vary the timestamp of the block by up to 30 seconds.